# php mysqli non prepared to prepare statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

so i have a login page which works very well using php mysqli, but is non prepare so i usually use mysqli_real_escape to secure the data.

But am now migrating to using prepared statement, have manage this with my register page and this as work very well.

**here is my non prepared login code:**

```
        $loginQuery = "select * from user where user_name = '$user_name' AND password = '$password'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$loginQuery);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){

                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); 

   // password verify
if (password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {

                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];
                $_SESSION['user_name'] = strtoupper($row['user_name']);
                $user_type = strtolower($row['user_type']);
                if(strtolower($user_type) == 'member'){ 

                    $_SESSION['user_type'] = 'member';  
                    //header('Location: member-dashboard-home.php');
                    header('Location: profile.php');

                }elseif(strtolower($user_type) == 'admin' || strtolower($user_type) == 'leader'){

                    $_SESSION['user_type'] = strtolower($user_type);                                        
                    //header('Location: admin-dashboard-home.php');
                    header('Location: profile.php');
                }


        }else{
                $_SESSION['main_notice'] = "Invalid login details!";
                header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);exit();
        }
```

**And below is my effort in using prepared statement.**

```
       $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT user_name FROM user WHERE user_name = ? ");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $user_name);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($user_name);
      if($res = $stmt->num_rows()){

        $row = $stmt->fetch_array($res);

    // password verify
    if (password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {

                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];
                $_SESSION['user_name'] = strtoupper($row['user_name']);
                $user_type = strtolower($row['user_type']);
                if(strtolower($user_type) == 'member'){ 

                    $_SESSION['user_type'] = 'member';  
                    //header('Location: member-dashboard-home.php');
                    header('Location: profile.php');
      //  exit;

                }elseif(strtolower($user_type) == 'admin' || strtolower($user_type) == 'leader'){

                    $_SESSION['user_type'] = strtolower($user_type);                                        
                    //header('Location: admin-dashboard-home.php');
                    header('Location: profile.php');
        //exit;
                }

    }else{
                $_SESSION['main_notice'] = "Invalid username OR password details, please try again!";
                header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);exit();
          }    
}
```

I didn't get any error code when i tried to login, but the form just return blank and didn't redirect to user profile.

I don't think this is redirection issue tho or is it?

i don't i arrange the `$stmt` properly, hopefully you guy see what i can't.

thanks in advance

Comment: `num_rows` is not a function, it's a property. Refer to online manuals and also read your error logs.

Comment: Also, a *blank screen* means something is broken. Add these lines `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your PHP scripts to see what the error is.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul thanks for the error report code. i did include at the top and i receive this error `Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in /home***/connection.php`... here is my connection code `$con = new mysqli("localhost", "***", "***", "***");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}`

Comment: i used the same connect for my other file and all work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment,

> i did include at the top and i receive this error Notice: **Undefined variable: mysqli in /home/connection.php...** ...

Look at your code here,

```
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "***", "***", "***"); 
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) { 
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error; 
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Your connection handler is `$con`, not `$mysqli`, it should be like this:

```
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "***", "***", "***"); 
if ($con->connect_errno) { 
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $con->connect_errno . ") " . $con->connect_error; 
}
```

**Update(1):** Change your code in the following way,

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name = ? ");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $user_name);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
if($result->num_rows){
    // username exists
    $row = $result->fetch_array();

    // your code

}else{
    // username doesn't exist

    // your code

}
```

Comment: i did amend the connection err... but am still getting return blank field.

Comment: @OlamilekanOshodi I've updated my answer. Please see the **Update(1)** section of my answer.

Comment: thanks for amending the code, have tried some similar before as well using the get result. am now getting this error `Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() `.

Comment: @OlamilekanOshodi *hmm*, I suspect *mysqlnd* native driver is not installed in your system. Paste your code on [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/index.php) and give me it's link here.

Comment: @OlamilekanOshodi No, the one where you're using prepared statements and getting *Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()* error.

Comment: @OlamilekanOshodi May be *mysqlnd* driver is not installed in your system. Test your application with this code snippet, [http://pastebin.com/ZDqSwUT7](http://pastebin.com/ZDqSwUT7)

Comment: allow me a moment to test that.

Comment: that works beautifully, but am a little a bit confused and i will learn how that work. so i notice 1. You select more  data like id, user_name, password and then you bind the result, but in the result you used another variables which is same i have in my database field

Comment: i also notice you change the row in password varify and session row to variables

Comment: why is and what different do they make.

Comment: @OlamilekanOshodi `->bind_result()` method basically binds your variable to the prepared statement. So if you do `SELECT * FROM ...` and then do `$stmt->bind_result($id, $username, ...);`, it won't work because you need to specify each column in the `SELECT` statement. And when you do `->fetch()`, it just fetch results into those bound variables.

Comment: @OlamilekanOshodi Please mark the answer as *accepted* if it resolved your issue. [How to accept answer on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: absolutely right, cause had just tested it now it doesn't work when using `SELECT * `, but does it matter if i have the store_result before binding the result.

Comment: yes i will accept. Thanks for your help mate, really appreciate it.

Comment: @OlamilekanOshodi you can do that but it's not logically correct because you need to make sure that the query actually returns something from the table. So first use `->store_result()` followed by `->num_rows` to make sure that you have something in hand, and then bind the result variables and make use of them.

Comment: thanks mate, really appreciate all your help, have now used that method to fix couple things. you are the man. :)

Comment: @OlamilekanOshodi Thanks, glad I could help. *Cheers! :-)*

Comment: hello thanks for the previous help. have open a new question is very similar to previous one and i was hoping you could help. here is the link `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39696679/fetching-user-data-with-prepared-statement`

Comment: @OlamilekanOshodi See my answer there.