# fetching user data with prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

hey guy so am trying to create profile table by displaying user data. have used some code samples that you'll see in the code below, have commented some out so watch out.

**here is my code**

```
    // $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = ? ");
    // $stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
    // if($stmt->execute()){
    // //$result = $stmt->get_result();
    // if($result->num_rows > 0){
    // //     username exists
    // //$stmt->bind_result($firstname, $lastname, $user_type, $email, $profession);
    //   echo 'No Data Found for this use';
    // }else{
    //    $row = $stmt->fetch_array();
    // $stmt = "select firstname, lastname, user_type, profession, email, dob, gender, country, phone, bio, address, created_at from user where id = $userId";
    // if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($stmt)) {

    //     /* execute statement */
    //      $stmt->execute();
    // // $stmt->store_result();
    // // if($stmt->num_rows){
    //     /* bind result variables */
    //     $stmt->bind_result($firstname, $lastname, $user_type, $profession, $email, $dob, $gender, $country, $phone, $bio, $address, $created_at);

    //     /* fetch values */
    //     while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    // //    }

    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT firstname, lastname, user_type, profession, email, dob, gender, country, phone, bio, address, created_at FROM user WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $userId);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();   
    if(!$stmt->num_rows > 0) {  
      echo 'No Data Found for this user';
      }
    else {
    $stmt->bind_result($firstname, $lastname, $user_type, $profession, $email, $dob, $gender, $country, $phone, $bio, $address, $created_at);  // <- Add; #args = #cols in SELECT

       $row = $stmt->fetch();
```

As you can see there are 1 open bracket `}` in the code above, that because it was wrap with the HTML.

**below is the html code**

```
     <!-- self post back url  -->
  <?php
      $url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  ?>

  <table>

        <tr>
          <td>
                <center>
                      <img src="userfiles/avatars/<?php echo $row['avatar'];?>" width="150" height="150">
                  </center>

          </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
           <td><label><strong>First Name</strong></label></td>
           <td></td>
            <td><label><?php echo $row['firstname'];?> </td>
        </tr>
          <tr>
           <td><label><strong>Last Name</strong></label></td>
           <td></td>
            <td><label><?php echo $row['lastname'];?> </td>
        </tr>
   <tr>
           <td><label><strong>User Type</strong></label></td>
           <td></td>
            <td><label><?php echo $row['user_type'];?> </td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
           <td><label><strong>Profession</strong></label></td>
           <td></td>
            <td><label><?php echo $row['profession'];?> </td>
        </tr>
     <tr>
         <tr>
           <td><label><strong>Phone</strong></label></td>
           <td></td>
            <td><label><?php echo $row['phone'];?> </td>
        </tr>
     <tr>
           <td><label><strong>Gender</strong></label></td>
           <td></td>
            <td><label><?php echo $row['gender'];?> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td><label><strong>Date Of Birth</strong></label></td>
           <td></td>
            <td><label><?php echo $row['dob'];?> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td><label><strong>Email</strong></label></td>
           <td></td>
            <td><label><?php echo $row['email'];?> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td><label><strong>Country</strong></label></td>
           <td></td>
            <td><label><?php echo $row['country'];?> </td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
           <td><label><strong>Address</strong></label></td>
           <td></td>
            <td><label><?php echo $row['address'];?> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td><label><strong>Biography</strong></label></td>
           <td></td>
            <td><label><?php echo $row['bio'];?> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td><label><strong>Join Date</strong></label></td>
           <td></td>
            <td><label><?php echo $row['created_at'];?> </td>
        </tr>

  </table>

  <?php 

     }  

  $mysqli->close(); 
  ?>
```

The above code work, but no user data displayed. here is screenshot: http://prntscr.com/cmfa0n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this statement here,

```
$row = $stmt->fetch();
```

From [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php),

`->fetch()` method returns,

> TRUE  Success. Data has been fetched 
>   FALSE   Error occurred 
>   NULL    No more rows/data exists or data truncation occurred

It doesn't return any row from the result set.

With the `->bind_result()` method, you've already binded variables for result storage, and what `->fetch()` does is, it fetches results from a prepared statement into the bound variables, so you can directly use `$firstname`, `$lastname`, `$user_type` etc. in your table.

**Note:** You haven't selected `avatar` column in the `SELECT` statement, and add `$avatar` in the `$stmt->bind_result($firstname, $lastname,...)` statement also.

Comment: OK have had a look at the doc... is what you are trying to say is I don't need the ->fetch ();

Comment: sorry for my ignorance

Comment: @OlamilekanOshodi Yes, you do need `->fetch()`. What I'm saying is, after this statement `$stmt->fetch();`, you can directly use those bounded variables `$firstname`, `$lastname` in your table to display all data.

Comment: oh I get it. OK I will give it ago and I will get back to you. thanks buddy.

Comment: @RajdeeopPaul... so am still not getting any result. here is my final code.

Comment: `$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT firstname, lastname, user_type, profession, email, dob, gender, country, phone, bio, address, created_at FROM user WHERE id = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $userId);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();   
        if(!$stmt->num_rows > 0) {  
          echo 'No Data Found for this user';
          }else {
       $row = $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->bind_result($firstname, $lastname, $user_type, $profession, $email, $dob, $gender, $country, $phone, $bio, $address, $created_at);`

Comment: @OlamilekanOshodi This line `if(!$stmt->num_rows > 0) { ...` looks suspicious, change this line to `if($stmt->num_rows == 0) { ...`. Also, do `echo $stmt->num_rows;` to see how many results you're getting.

Comment: @OlamilekanOshodi And oh, first do `$stmt->bind_result($firstname, $lastname, ...);` **and then**  do `$stmt->fetch();`, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: well here is what have tried... http://prntscr.com/cmg8rm and am receiving a blank result

Comment: maybe this will help... here is my none prepare statement.  `//    $getUserQuery = "select * from user where id = $userId";
        //    $resultData =   mysqli_query($con, $getUserQuery);
        //       if(!mysqli_num_rows($resultData)){
        //        echo 'No Data Found for this user';
        //       }else{
        //        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultData);` that have commented out, it works, what the easier way to turn this to statement. other than what have presently

Comment: @OlamilekanOshodi You haven't read [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39696679/fetching-user-data-with-prepared-statement/39697226?noredirect=1#comment66695034_39697226), have you? Your code should be like this, [http://pastebin.com/UWJ8J6Xw](http://pastebin.com/UWJ8J6Xw). Also, I told you to do `echo $stmt->num_rows;`, what does it show?

Comment: Hi Ok... sorry about that, i was trying to fix on my side as well, so have tried the pastebin code, and have also echo it as well. here the screenshot http://prntscr.com/cmgf1q

Comment: am thinking is it because i have my html like this? `<tr>
               <td><label><strong>First Name</strong></label></td>
                <td><label><?php echo $row['firstname'];?> </td>
            </tr>`

Comment: @OlamilekanOshodi As I told you, you can directly use those bound variables in your table, like this: `<tr> <td><label><strong>First Name</strong></label></td> <td><label><?php echo $firstname; ?> </td> </tr>` etc.

Comment: That works beautifully, i think since i wasn't using the variable `$row = $stmt->fetch()` anymore i should amend the html `<?php echo $row['firstname'];?> ` to `<?php echo $firstname; ?>` as you;ve suggested. Now it works.

Comment: @OlamilekanOshodi *Glad I could help you. :-)*

Comment: hey mate... how are you. Please was hoping you could help with code here. `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39827931/mysqli-to-prepared-statement?noredirect=1#comment66946049_39827931` if you are not too busy.

Comment: @OlamilekanOshodi I've given an answer there. Hopefully that will resolve your issue.