# mysqli to prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

Am trying to convert mysqli to prepare statement. Have being making alot of progress with most of them,but is unusual. I hope some can help with it.

**here is my mysqli code**

```
            $UpdateQuery = "UPDATE user SET avatar ='$NewImageName' WHERE user_name = '$temp'";
            $InsertQuery = "INSERT INTO user (avatar) VALUES ('$NewImageName')";

           $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name = '$temp'");
            if( mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                if(!empty($_FILES['ImageFile']['name'])){
                    mysqli_query($con, $UpdateQuery)or die(mysqli_error($con));
                    header("location:edit-profile.php?user_name=$temp");
                }
            } 
            else {
                mysqli_query($con, $InsertQuery)or die(mysqli_error($con));
                header("location:edit-profile.php?user_name=$temp");
            }
```

**These is my attempt to try and fix it with prepared statement**

```
           if(!($stmtUpdate = $con->prepare("UPDATE user SET avatar = ? WHERE user_name = ?"))) {
        echo "Prepare failed: (" . $con->errno . ")" . $con->error;
    }
        if(!($stmtInsert = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO user ( avatar ) VALUES ( ? )"))) {
        echo "Prepare failed: (" . $con->errno . ")" . $con->error;
    } 
        if(!($stmtSelect = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name = ? "))) {
        echo "Prepare failed: (" . $con->errno . ")" . $con->error;
    }        
        if(!$stmt->bind_param('sss', $temp, $NewImageName, $temp)) {
      echo "Binding paramaters failed:(" . $stmt->errno . ")" . $stmt->error;
    }      
        if(!$stmt->execute()){
             echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno .")" . $stmt->error;
    }

    $stmt->store_result();  
    if($stmt->num_rows == 0) {
           if(!empty($_FILES['ImageFile']['name'])){
                    $con->prepare($stmtUpdate)or die(mysqli_error($con));
                    header("location:edit-profile.php?user_name=$temp");
             exit;
                }
            } else {
        $stmt->bind_result($avatar, $avatar, $temp);
        $stmt->fetch();
          header("location:edit-profile.php?user_name=$temp");
        }

   $stmt->close();
```

I Although i run it once and i get error, i know am most be missing some thing.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: here is the error am getting `Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in ****/edit-profile.php on line 67`

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488035/call-to-a-member-function-bind-param-on-a-non-object)

Comment: Thanks for your help... but that doesn't answer my question much. i have 3 query there `Update, Select and Insert`

Comment: the first thing i need to know is, is my prepared statement code right?

Comment: Try adding space after mysqli_query($con, $UpdateQuery) and before or. So, it should be like mysqli_query($con, $UpdateQuery) or die(). Similarly other places

Comment: hi, am trying to convert this mysqli to prepared statement. the answer you gave above the mysqli.

Comment: the mysqli code works perfectly the way it is... but i need to prepare it for security reason

Comment: Also try moving your $stmt->close(); inside your if conditon

Comment: `$stmt->close();` was remove didn't solve the problem. can you tell me please is my prepare method correct initailly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt to change those non-prepared statements to prepared statements is wrong. Few issues are:

- There's no need to create three separate statement objects for `SELECT`, `UPDATE` and `INSERT`, only one statement object is enough. Having said that, always close the prepared statement using using it again for your query.
- `if(!$stmt->bind_param(...`, `if(!$stmt->execute()` etc. `$stmt` is not a statement object, you never even created or used this variable anywhere. And that's why you're getting this *Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object ...* error.
- Looking at your non-prepared code above, there's no need to use `->bind_result()` or `->fetch()` method, simply perform `INSERT` or `UPDATE` operation and redirect the user to a different page.

Your prepared code should be like this: (The underlying logic strictly resembles your non-prepared code)

```
if(!($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name = ?"))){
    die("Prepare failed: (" . $con->errno . ") " . $con->error);
} 
if(!$stmt->bind_param('s', $temp)){
    die("Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error);
}
if($stmt->execute()){
    $stmt->store_result();
    $num_rows = $stmt->num_rows;
    $stmt->close();

    if($num_rows){
        if(!empty($_FILES['ImageFile']['name'])){
            if(!($stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE user SET avatar = ? WHERE user_name = ?"))){
                die("Prepare failed: (" . $con->errno . ") " . $con->error);
            } 
            if(!$stmt->bind_param('ss', $NewImageName, $temp)){
                die("Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error);
            }
            if($stmt->execute()){
                $stmt->close();
                header("location:edit-profile.php?user_name=" . $temp);
                exit();
            }else{
                die("Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error);
            }
        }
    }else{
        if(!($stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO user (avatar) VALUES (?)"))){
            die("Prepare failed: (" . $con->errno . ") " . $con->error);
        } 
        if(!$stmt->bind_param('s', $NewImageName)){
            die("Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error);
        } 
        if($stmt->execute()){
            $stmt->close();
            header("location:edit-profile.php?user_name=" . $temp);
            exit();
        }else{
            die("Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error);
        }
    }
}else{
    die("Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error);
}
```

Comment: as always, thanks for having a look at the code. Have used it he works like a charm. I will never have taught to seperate it this way, but now have learn, also closing each statement after each query have learn as well

Comment: Thanks so much... am using most of your previous method in my other codes.

Comment: @OlamilekanOshodi Glad I could help. Please *accept* the answer if it resolved your issue. :-)